# Having a problem when trying to make a discord bot on a raspberry pi

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, discord.js

I was making a bot on my raspberry in node.js with this code:

```js
const config = require('./config.json');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', async() => {
    console.log('bot is ready');

})

client.on('message', async(msg) => {
    if(msg.author.bot) return;
    if(!msg.guild) return;

    var prefix = config.prefix;
    if(!msg.content.toLowerCase().startswith(prefix)) return;

    var args = msg.content.split(' ')
    var cmd = args.shift().slice(prefix.length).toLowerCase();
    try{
        var file = require(`./commands/${cmd}.js`);
        file.run(client, msg, args)

    }catch(err) {
        console.warn(err)
    }
})

client.login(config.token);
```

config.json (also in token I didn't actualy put my token):

```json
{
    "token": "my token",
    "prefix": ">"
}
```

but when I run it I just says:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/pi'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

does anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: What discordjs and nodejs versions are you using?

Comment: I think its: 16.7.0